# if else statement not working(nodejs,html)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have this code that will get the year from a html form and im trying to set an argument for it but the else statement never seem to execute. Any clue as to why?

```js
exports.printyear = function(request, response) {
        let form = new formi.IncomingForm();
        form.parse(request, function(error, field, file) {
            let year = field.year;
            let currenturl = "";
            console.log("YEAR");
            console.log(year);
            if (year === 2007 | 2008 | 2009) {
                currenturl = "websiteurl" + year + ".xml";
            } else {
                currenturl = "websiteurl" + year + ".json";
            }
            console.log(currenturl);
            response.end();
        });
```

Comment: `year===2007|2008|2009` won't work how you expect. You need to test `year` against each value _separately_

Comment: year===2007||year===2008|| year===2009

Comment: `if (year===2007|2008|2009)` thats not how `if` statements work. You need `if(year == 2007 || year == 2008 || year == 2009){...}`

Comment: You could be fancy and use an array: `if ([2007, 2008, 2009].includes(year)) {...}`.

Comment: my god, actually forgot about that. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way of using `or` in conditions is to separate them.

### Change

```
if (year===2007|2008|2009) {
```

### To

```
if (year===2007 || year===2008 || year===2009) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The issues seems to be this line:

`if (year===2007|2008|2009) {`

You need to compare each value one by one like this:

```js
if (year===2007||year===2008||year===2009)
```

What you're doing right now is a bitwise operator `|`

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR)

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, the syntax in the if statement is is not valid JS. Try the following:

```
if (year === 2007 || year === 2008 || year === 2009) {
    currenturl = "websiteurl" + year + ".xml";
} else {
    currenturl = "websiteurl" + year + ".json";
}
```